# What is an "x-type density matrix"?

Tags: density-matrix

i want to know what is a x-type density matrix structure? i want to know the general case of it.
is this something like this?

[image]

can one of matrix elements be 0?
unfortunately there is no info about it in google.
also i want know under what conditions a x-type state is entanglement?

Comment: Can you provide some reference to what is it? where did you see the term "x-type density matrix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is essentially just, yes. Though of course there will be some constraints on those coefficients, to ensure you get an Hermitian positive-semidefinite unit-trace matrix.

See e.g. [Quesada et al. 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3689) for more info about the properties of $X$ states.